# Autoconf without GLib breaks with syntax error on configure

Tags: glib, autoconf

If I don't have pkg-config installed nor glib my configure breaks with a syntax error when running `./configure`. Is there a way to break with `AC_MSG_ERROR`?

```
./configure: line 4001: syntax error near unexpected token `GLIB2,'
./configure: line 4001: `  PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB2, glib-2.0, , as_fn_error $? "glib needed" "$LINENO" 5)'
```

--

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(GTK, [], [gtk="$enabled"], gtk=no)

if test "$gtk" = "yes"; then
    AC_CHECK_LIB([gtk-x11-2.0], [gtk_init], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([gtk needed])])
else
    AC_CHECK_PROG(HAVE_PKG_CONFIG, pkg-config, yes)
    if test x"$HAVE_PKG_CONFIG" != x"yes" ; then
        AC_MSG_ERROR([pkg-config])
    fi
    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB2, glib-2.0, [], AC_MSG_ERROR([glib needed]))
    AC_SUBST(GLIB2_CFLAGS)
    AC_SUBST(GLIB2_LIBS)
    AC_CHECK_LIB([glib-2.0], [g_list_append], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([glib needed])])
fi

AM_CONDITIONAL([GTK], [test "x$gtk" = "xyes"])
```

Answer (score 4):

The `configure` script was generated incorrectly, in absence of pkg.m4. For all non-basic macros that don't start with `AC_*` it's a good idea to distribute them with the source code for this reason, so you can at least get a correct `configure` script.

That said, pkg-config is pretty ubiquitous nowadays, why are you generating a `configure` script from a system that doesn't have it? You could simply `make dist` from a "better" system, and build from the output tarball (that will contain a valid `configure` script).

Comment: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` works great if `pkg-config` is installed. However, since not all systems have it, then I'd need to add an extra dependency to the program I'm building. If an alternative to glib was enabled, then I shouldn't need to have `pkg-config` installed to run configure, otherwise, use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.

Comment: Once `PKG_*` macros are correctly expanded you can use the `ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND` argument to handle either the absence of the library you are checking, or the complete absence of pkg-config (in this case all `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` will invoke `ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND`). As I said, you should not be generating the configure script everywhere, generate it once on any system with enough system tools, then use the tarball on the less capable systems.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a check for pkg-config should do the trick:

```
# require pkg-config
AC_PATH_PROG([PKG_CONFIG], [pkg-config], [no])
AS_IF([test "x$PKG_CONFIG" = "xno"],[
   AC_MSG_ERROR([
   *** The pkg-config script could not be found. Make sure it is
   *** in your path, or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable
   *** to the full path to pkg-config.])
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting the same error. It seems it doesn't like `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` if GLib is not installed.